# Updating flutter_svg to recent version - DrawableRoot doesnt exist

Tags: flutter, svg

So I updated [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#flutter_svg) library from 1.1.1+1 to the latest version which is 2.0.7 and discovered that the class I used to use to render custom svg from a string is now deprecated.

The code used to be like this:

```
final rawSvg = await rootBundle.loadString(assetPath);
final DrawableRoot svgRoot = await svg.fromSvgString(rawSvg, rawSvg);
final Picture picture = svgRoot.toPicture(
  size: this.widget.size,
  colorFilter: this.widget.colorFilter,
);

return picture.toImage(
  this.widget.spacing.width.toInt(),
  this.widget.spacing.height.toInt(),
);
```

Now since DrawableRoot is no longer available i head up to the documentation of the library and tried what the author suggested as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
final String rawSvg = '''<svg ...>...</svg>''';
final PictureInfo pictureInfo = await vg.loadPicture(SvgStringLoader(rawSvg), null);

// You can draw the picture to a canvas:
canvas.drawPicture(pictureInfo.picture);

// Or convert the picture to an image:
final ui.Image image = pictureInfo.picture.toImage(...);

pictureInfo.picture.dispose();
```

And it works except that i can't seem to find a way to assign a size as i used to in the older code and a color.

I tried the SVGTheme class within the library but with no luck.

Keep in mind guys that i want the function to return a ui.Image object because I'm using it in another one that creates somewhat of a watermark:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _setupImage(this.widget.svgPath),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<ui.Image> image) {
    if ((image.hasData)) {
      return ShaderMask(
        child: Container(color: Colors.white),
        shaderCallback: (bounds) => ImageShader(
          image.data!,
          TileMode.repeated,
          TileMode.repeated,
          _transformMatrix.storage,
        ),
        blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
      );
    } else {
      return SizedBox();
    }
  },
)
```

Any suggestions on how i can achieve the same output with the new approach?

Answer (score 0):

Size no longer needs to pass to SvgPicture from **flutter_Svg 0.3.1** - its size is determined by parent size.
wrap it with `Container()` or`SizedBox()` and use your preferable size to it.
try this.

Comment: Yes but I'm not using SvgPicture because i don't want a widget returned. I want a returned ui.Image object that I'm using in another function.

I will update the question.

Comment: Can you please update that which version of the package it was and now wich. versionyou are using?

Comment: I updated it with the versions.